# WPBakery Post grid: How to open post grid´s elements in another window (_blank)?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, visual-composer

I created a post grid showing some PDF documents, but I need them to be open in a new window. How can I do? I found the following code, but it doesn´t work:

```
jQuery(window).load(function() {
jQuery('.vc_grid-item .vc_grid-item-mini').on('click', 'a', function(e){ 
    e.preventDefault(); 
    var url = jQuery(this).attr('href'); 
    window.open(url, '_blank');
});
```

});

Answer (score 1):

you can simply do:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   jQuery('.vc_grid-item .vc_grid-item-mini a').attr('target', '_blank');
});
```

This adds the target attribute with '_blank' value to the a tag.

Comment: Hi, and thanks for your advice. Unfortunately it doesn´t work on my side. And what should I do if need to use this jquery just on one WP page?

Comment: @Dino9 You can do that with php in your theme>>functions.php checking if the loaded page is the wanted page. Then you enqueue your js file with your jquery code in it.